# Python code generation: Create functions with varying but known number of parameters of the fly

Tags: python, code-generation, metaprogramming

Doing some metaprogramming in Python, I have to create a function on the fly. My problem is that the number of parameters is not determined until generating the code. So different generated functions will have different parameters with different names. But when the function is generated, all information is available and I do NOT want to use `**args`! Here's an example:

```
# information collected by my codgen process
arg_names = ['param_a','param_b','param_c']
some_callable = ClassDeterminedWhileGeneratingCode
```

What I would like to generate, is a function like this one, which will be added to a class:

```
def my_fkt(self,param_a,param_b,param_c):
    instance = some_callable(param_a=param_a,param_b=param_b,param_c=param_c)
    self.do_something(instance)
    return instance.generate_result()
```

I'm quite used to generate functions using higher order functions, but that does not help if the number of parameters is not fixed. I'm quite sure, that I have somewhere seen code creating functions using `type.FunctionType`. But I was not able to find any documentation about that.

Comment: Are these functions used in construction of a complete class definition, or just adhoc'd for further instances of a class?

Comment: In construction of a complete class definition. The function will be generated inside `__new__` of a metaclass and will be put into the `classdict` which will be passed to `type.__new__`.

Comment: Why *don't* you want to use `*args` and `**kw`; they are a perfect fit for your needs here. You are essentially creating a decorator, and you do not need to generate code if you use `*args` and `**kw` to capture and pass on function arguments.

Comment: The real `my_fkt` is a bit more complex, so I'm not sure if it would be possible to implement everything in a decorator. But the main purpose for not using `*args` and `**kw` is, that I want to have nice error messages. This is part of a bigger codgen project, so if it's possible at all, I would like to generate the functions exactly as I would implement them by hand, just to reduce confusion when debugging and so on.

Comment: This sounds similar to what `functools.wraps` does, maybe take a look at its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at,

http://snipplr.com/view/17819/

if you want to manipulate the argument names, you should replace "y.func_code.co_varnames" by a tuple with the given names.

Cheers, Uwe

Answer (score 0):

Try convtools library, it supports input_args and a lot of other stuff, which is all about generating ad hoc code.